# Spring boot maven plugin build-image : how to pass docker host, bindings and other options as args to mvn spring-boot:build-image

Tags: spring-boot, docker-image, spring-boot-maven-plugin, buildpack

I have the following spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <docker>
            <host>tcp://<docker-host>:2375</host>
        </docker>
        <image>
            <buildpacks>
                <buildpack>gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/amazon-corretto:latest</buildpack>
                <buildpack>paketo-buildpacks/java</buildpack>
            </buildpacks>
            <verboseLogging>true</verboseLogging>
            <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
            <env>
                <BP_DEBUG>true</BP_DEBUG>
            </env>
            <bindings>
                <binding>${basedir}/bindings:/platform/bindings</binding>
            </bindings>
        </image>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>executable</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I want to pass the `docker host` and `bindings` as args to `mvn spring-boot:build-image`

I tried `-Dspring-boot.build-image.dockerHost`, `-Dspring-boot.build-image.docker.host`, `-Dspring-boot.dockerHost` etc, however,  nothing worked for me.
I am yet to try something for bindings:  `${basedir}/bindings:/platform/bindings`

Our requirement is to set both `docker host` and `bindings` as `mvn spring-boot:build-image` args to keep the `pom.xml` generic as far as possible.

Not sure what I am missing here?

P.S. Setting the `DOCKER_HOST` as `env` variable works.

Also, I can use `${docker.host}` for host and  `${binding}` for bindings and then run the following command:

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image -Ddocker.host=mydockerhost:2375   
  -Dbinding="my/absolute-path/to/bindings:platform/bindings"
```

I guess it's not the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do better than what you already envisioned (creating your own maven pom variables to inject values into the plugin settings)

A [similar issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/31024) was raised recently and the resolution was just a matter of [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/34517).

Back to your issue, you can see through [the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/BuildImageMojo.java#LL117C2-L117C2) or through the documentation that there is no way to configure [`dockerHost`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.docker-daemon) nor [`bindings` (although as you mentioned the env variable `DOCKER_HOST` is an option)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization) via Spring properties.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The only drawback I find with  this approach is that it makes mandatory to use certain param(s) e.g. even if I don't need bindings, some binding value will be used either from <properties><binding>some-default-value</properties> or from command line.

Comment: Yes, that is true